# Adding libusb library to a Qt project in osx

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qmake, libusb

I've been attempting for the past 16 hours to attach the libusb library to a Qt project without much success. I would appreciate any input on the matter, it's getting frustrating.

The .pro file is this:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH +=/usr/local/include/libusb-1.0
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -libusb-1.0.a
LIBS += -L<libusb.h>
```

Source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libusb.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler output:

```
13:01:50: Running steps for project lallala...
13:01:50: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
13:01:50: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" -w
make: Entering directory `/Users/MAXIMUS/Documents/workspace/lallala-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_0_clang_64bit_SDK-Debug'
/Users/MAXIMUS/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/clang_64/bin/qmake -spec macx-g++42 CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=x86_64 CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug -o Makefile ../lallala/lallala.pro
make: Leaving directory `/Users/MAXIMUS/Documents/workspace/lallala-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_0_clang_64bit_SDK-Debug'
make: Entering directory `/Users/MAXIMUS/Documents/workspace/lallala-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_0_clang_64bit_SDK-Debug'
g++-4.2 -headerpad_max_install_names -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -o lallala main.o   -L/usr/local/lib -libusb-1.0.a -L<libusb.h> 
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `g++-4.2 -headerpad_max_install_names -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -o lallala main.o   -L/usr/local/lib -libusb-1.0.a -L<libusb.h> '
make: *** [lallala] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/Users/MAXIMUS/Documents/workspace/lallala-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_0_clang_64bit_SDK-Debug'
13:01:50: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project lallala (kit: Desktop Qt 5.0.0 clang 64bit (SDK))
When executing step 'Make'
```

Comment: Hi John. Cannot you just use [pkg-config](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtserialport/source/6e75610dff5fb96ebd72cfb40ba7cbfea4bd21b7:src/serialport/serialport-lib.pri#L11)? That is how we did in QtSerialPort, although make sure it is not "local" installation. Failing that, have you checked [this link](http://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/article/how-to-use-usb-devices-from-qt-framework)?

Comment: Hello Laszlo, thank you for your input and the links. I just found a way to add the library through a GUI I'll see if that works for me.

Comment: Gotcha! Selected the answer, sorry about that ;)

Comment: I'm still getting used to this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forming my comment into a proper answer; this is not the correct syntax to use:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -libusb-1.0.a
LIBS += -L<libusb.h>
```

The proper one would be this:

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lusb-1.0

or

LIBS += -l/full/path/to/libusb-1.0.a

You can drop the second `LIBS` line in your initial attempt because you have already specified the path in the former, and putting an "include" statement in there would not be reasonable anyhow. So, this is what you could write for your complete .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH +=/usr/local/include/libusb-1.0
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lusb-1.0
```

This is not Qt specific, just generic linkage issue: `-lfoo` extends to `$(prefix)foo$(suffix)`, where the prefix and suffix are figured out automatically based on the platform. That is, the prefix would be `lib` in your case, and suffix would be either `.a` or `.so` on Unix, probably `.dylib` on Mac, etc.

You may wish to look into pkg-config support if it is possible to establish. In that case, you would write something like this what we did in QtSerialPort:

```
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += libudev
```

Yet another option is to add the GUI through the QtCreator IDE or similar IDE that you may be using. There is an option usually in the "Linker" section to add a library. Here are two screenshots from my QtCreator:

[image]

[image]

Click on the project name on the left in the project source tree navigator, and select `Add Library`. Then the first screenshot will come up, and you can select the external option, and then you can see the second.

It is needless to say that you would need to run qmake after these changes to generate the corresponding Makefile on your desired platform.

Comment: Thank you so much! You sir, are amazing. I used sample code I found online and compiled it with out a hitch. I still have a couple of questions if you don't mind, how come its lusb-1.0? I could not find the file in the directory. Also, any chance you could direct me to a link where I could learn more about the concept of pkg-config? I still don't understand what role it plays exactly. Thanks again! I posted the .pro code that worked for me.

Comment: @DutyClean: this is not Qt specific, just generic linkage issue. `-lfoo` extends to $(prefix)foo$(suffix) where the prefix and suffix are figured out automatically based on the platform. That is, prefix would be "lib" in your case, and suffix would be ".a" or ".so".

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is the following:
-L%LIBRARY_PATH% to make a specific path visible and
-l%LIBRARY_NAME% to link a specific library that is located in a visible path

so I guess this should work (I don't think you need the .a extension):

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -llibusb-1.0

and I have no idea what this would do:
LIBS += -L
so I guess I'd remove it.

Once fixed **run qmake** then build...

Hope it helps...

Comment: some text was cut. I meant remove the last line of your pro file